# Indent chapters after part

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

I'm trying to indent the chapters apearing after a part in the table of contents. I've seen that it easy using a Koma script, but I have an imposed document class.

This is what I'd like to do:
[image: Without indenting the Bibliogrpahy or later the Conclusion]

Here is a part of the code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{Latex/Classes/PhDthesisPSnPDF} 

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents 
\listoffigures 
\listoftables 
\mainmatter 
\chapter{General introduction} 
\section{Noise sources in aero-engines} 
\section{Combustion noise} 
\subsection{Direct noise} 
\subsection{Indirect noise} 

\part{Towards a better understanding ...} 
\chapter*{Introduction} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction} 
\chapter{The Entropy Wave Generator experiment} 
. 
. 
. 
\bibliographystyle{myplainnat} 
\bibliography{./biblio} 
\end{document}
```

And indeed PhDthesisPSnPDF is an "inhouse made classe"
Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you please add  a minimal example of your code?

Comment: Which is your 'imposed' document class?

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : 
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{Latex/Classes/PhDthesisPSnPDF}
Where PhDthesisPSnPDF includes some definitions and packages and this part:
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
   \LoadClass[dvips, a4paper]{book}
\else
   \LoadClass[pdftex, a4paper]{book}
\fi

Comment: @touhami
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{Latex/Classes/PhDthesisPSnPDF}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\mainmatter
\chapter{General introduction}

\section{Noise sources in aero-engines}

\section{Combustion noise}

\subsection{Direct noise}
\subsection{Indirect noise}

\part{Towards a better understanding ...}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\chapter{The Entropy Wave Generator experiment}
.
.
.
\bibliographystyle{myplainnat}
\bibliography{./biblio} 
\end{document}

Thank you very much !

Comment: @linksse: Please post all that in your question above, not as comments. And I suspect `PHDThesisPSnPDF` is a very weird class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy   way is by using `adjustwidth` environment  from [changepage](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/changepage) package

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{PhDthesisPSnPDF} 

\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 
\listoffigures 
\listoftables 
\mainmatter 
\chapter{General introduction}
\section{Noise sources in aero-engines}
\section{Combustion noise}
\subsection{Direct noise} 
\subsection{Indirect noise} 

\part{Towards a better understanding ...} 
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{0cm}}% Begin

\chapter*{Introduction} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction} 
\chapter{The Entropy Wave Generator experiment} . . . 

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{adjustwidth}}%  End

\bibliographystyle{myplainnat} 
\bibliography{./biblio} 
\chapter{The Entropy Wave Generator experiment} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\protect\begin{adjustwidth}` and `\protect\end{adjustwidth}`. Using `\adjustwidth` and `\endadjustwidth` in the wild is not recommendable.

Comment: @linksse your welcome, did you see egreg's comment?

Comment: Yes, both options worked very well and finally took the option with begin and end.
Again, thank you very much.